# Is it worth doing a likely "LeetCode-style" interview with a big company if I have little experience with that format and only five days until then?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry

After applying to a big company (assuming it would be a long time before I heard back), I got a recruiter call within a few days asking to schedule a technical interview. I agreed, figuring there's a decent chance it would be a good fit. However, I'm not happy with the rate at which I'm completing LeetCode-style practice problems, which big Silicon Valley tech companies notoriously use. This company in particular does tend give easier ones from what I've read, or not lean on them as much and vary the format from team to team, but going in with this assumption might not be a good idea.

Would it be more constructive to continue with this interview, or to cancel and spend a significant amount of preparation time before? It seems common to read online that people spend months preparing for software engineering interviews at big tech.

Comment: If you fail the interviews with big tech companies, you may need to wait for at least 1 year to have another interview. Good luck with the interview if you plan to take it. Have fun. :-)

Comment: Seems that this particular company might be an exception, since candidates interview directly with their teams. They might not have the one year policy since you could be interviewing with any number of their teams at a given time.

Comment: @AustinConlon, Do it. Even if you get rejected, you'll be fine. And you'll be that much more motivated to practice for the next technical interviews you do. And yes, you may have to wait one year before you can interview again with that same company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big tech companies would probably be OK with just postponing. They know that you don't use these kinds of skills in your everyday job and need a fair amount of preparation.

It's definitely worth speaking to the recruiter and telling them straight out that you'd prefer to delay for a few weeks while you brush up on your algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If you cancel now and prepare for the interview, are you sure that after the preparation is complete, you will get another chance?

If yes, then cancel for now and prepare.

If no, then take some days off from your current job, prepare whatever you can and take the chance.